# Philadelphia Sitecore User Group: Sitecore Switchers, ReactJS and SXA

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** Wednesday, 30 November 2016 *at 6:00pm*
- **Date/Time (UTC):** Wednesday, 30 November 2016 *at 11:00pm*
- **Location:** EPAM Empathy Lab, 777 Appletree St, 8th Floor, Philadelphia, PA
- **Event Details:** [Meetup Details and RSVP](http://meetu.ps/e/CcCRW/tWK0z/f)
- **Contact:** @zachary_kniebel (Sitecore Community Slack)
- **Description:** The Philadelphia Sitecore community is in for a trifecta of meetup awesomeness, as EPAM Solution Architects [Alexander Smahin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexandersmagin/), [Dean Thrasher](https://www.linkedin.com/in/deanthrasher) and Brent Pinkstaff join Delphic Technical Architect [Zachary Kniebel](https://www.linkedin.com/in/zkniebel) in delivering a triple whammy: three meetups in one! You won't want to miss this! 
   
  Topics:
   
  - Sitecore+ReactJS - *Alexander Smahin* 
  - SXA - *Dean Thrasher and Brent Pinkstaff* 
  - Sitecore Switchers - *Zachary Kniebel*

Comment: I have added this event to the board. Community bulletin promotion will begin 10 days before the event.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Dmytro.

Comment: will it be broadcasted?

Comment: That's a great question, @Diego. I do not believe that there are any current plans for broadcasting it, but I can see if that can be arranged. If not, I will at least make sure that it is recorded.

Comment: I will update this post with any new info as it comes in

Comment: thanks Zachary.